# How to merge all files that end with .mk in a directory and subdirectories into one file?

Tags: linux

I have many makefiles in a top level directory and its subdirectories. I want to combine them all into one big .mk file, what's the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
cat $(find . -type f -name \*.mk) > output.mk
```

Example:

```
a.mk       # a
d1/b.mk    # b
d1/c.mk    # c
d1/d2/d.mk # d
```

Would produce in `output.mk`

```
a
b
c
d
```